# Relationship between work and kinetic energy?

Tags: energy, experimental-physics, work

Lab Question: What is the relationship between the work done on a car as it rolls down a ramp and its kinetic energy at the bottom of the ramp?

We have a 30 gram car that starts above a table and goes leaves the table horizontally. Our teacher said that we don't need to be experimenting for time. When I drop the car from the ramp, should I be measuring how far the car lands from the table? What data and calculations should I be doing to find the average work done by gravity, the speed of the car when leaving the table, and the average final kinetic energy?

Comment: The answers to these questions may be found in your physics book.  It is important to read that book, and closely follow the worked example problems.  If you just memorize an answer from this forum, you will not understand the key concepts, meaning that you will not do well on the test over this subject matter.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. This seems as a homework question and this site is not dedicated to homeworks. At least, you should show your efforts and where you are stuck with your problem.

Comment: @DavidWhite Thank you for the comments. This is a part of a lab that we were given and I don't know where to start.

Comment: @Ethan, I'll give you a hint.  Rolling down the ramp involves conservation of energy.  How far the car lands from the table involves projectile motion, which can be used to back-calculate the velocity of the car when it left the table.  This means that physics is cumulative, so the concepts you learned in previous chapters must be used in this lab.  If you "crammed" the night before the test in previous chapters and forgot key concepts as a result, you will have an uphill battle in reacquiring those concepts in time.